# Redirecting URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress website and some link checker plugins are reporting all the links broken in same way. Just have a look:

```
http://www.esmedicare.com/category/blog/page/2/locations.html ( parent page: http://www.esmedicare.com/category/blog/page/2/ )
http://www.esmedicare.com/hello-world/locations.html ( parent page: http://www.esmedicare.com/hello-world/ )
http://www.esmedicare.com/neonatal-care-2/locations.html ( parent page: http://www.esmedicare.com/neonatal-care-2/ )
http://www.esmedicare.com/dental-center/locations.html ( parent page: http://www.esmedicare.com/dental-center/
```

I just want to redirect all these pages to their parent pages shown in bracket but I dont know how to do it exactly.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding these rules in the htaccess file in your document root, above any wordpress rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/locations.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: ooopppss..Its not showing the parent page even. Please check it again.

Comment: @PhillipMclauren It's [working for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zGhxr.png). Are you sure you don't have browser cached or something?

Comment: Sorry sir..It was my mistake. Thanks for helping. Hats off !!